# Why does my sculpting not working like how it does on this video

Tags: modeling, sculpting

Ok, i am watching this video by blender guru https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OTX3ZdYvEA&t=430s and when he starts sculpting at 5:58 his brush seems to have a  "plus" sign for a cursor, "+". mine doesnt. i dont know what this is called or how to fix it but i think it is messing with my sculpting because mine is not doing what his is doing. help would be appreciated. i have been searching for help for hours.
ps here is what is happening to mine: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkjW5v_qJtM7j2v6-AJhqNbGJH0D?e=Jh4WlO

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to subdivide the mesh further to increase detail.

Try subdividing once more to increase the number of faces for the brush to work on.